# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT with separator

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table 'pincodes' as

```
-------------------------------------
| id  | name  |  parent_id  | value |
-------------------------------------
|  1  | State |     0       |   0   |
|  2  | City1 |     1       | 20220 |
|  3  | City2 |     1       | 20221 |
```

The result i need is

```
--------------------------
| 1 | State       |      |
| 2 | State>City1 | 20220|
| 3 | State>City2 | 20221|
--------------------------
```

What i tried out

```
SELECT id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY parent_id SEPARATOR ' &gt; ') AS name
FROM pincode
GROUP BY id ORDER BY name;
```

And the result for the above query is

```
--------------------
| 1 | State |      |
| 2 | City1 | 20220|
| 3 | City2 | 20221|
--------------------
```

what I need is the parent state should be appended to each city.

> Note: can anyone suggest a better question  title.

Comment: You don't need any aggregation. You just need a join.

Comment: Specify result for  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5dd00/1/0, do you want result from root like `State>City1>Subcity1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT p1.id, CONCAT(COALESCE(CONCAT(p2.name, '>'), ''),  p1.name), p1.value
FROM pincodes AS p1
LEFT JOIN pincodes AS p2 ON p1.parent_id = p2.id
ORDER BY p1.id
```

You can get the parent record using a `LEFT JOIN`. Using `CONCAT` function you can concatenate the name of the parent with the name of the child.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b7e59/4)

**EDIT:**

The above query works only for 2-level hierarchies. For additional levels you have to use additional `LEFT JOIN` operations. For a generic solution one has to use recursive CTEs that are not available in MySQL.

This is how the above query can be extended to handle 3-level hierarchies:

```
SELECT p1.id, 
       CONCAT(COALESCE(CONCAT(p3.name, '>'), ''),
              COALESCE(CONCAT(p2.name, '>'), ''),  
              p1.name), 
       p1.value
FROM pincodes AS p1
LEFT JOIN pincodes AS p2 ON p1.parent_id = p2.id
LEFT JOIN pincodes AS p3 ON p2.parent_id = p3.id
ORDER BY p1.id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d1d4/3)

Comment: Author doesn't specify but http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5dd00/1/0 will produce `City1>Subcity1` and not `State>City1>Subcity1`, probably recursive solution is needed

Comment: @lad2025 Yes, this is correct. My query works only for a 2-level hierarchy. For a generic solution one has to use recursive CTEs that are not available in MySQL.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos thanks for the SQL Fiddle ! Does the work for me and right now I am only with the 2-level hierarchy so not a problem